# Background network request from app

Tags: ios

As a slightly open question: Can/how does one send a network request every 5 minutes from a minimised iOS app?

In our case, we want to make sure that a certain message written when offline is sent as soon as the user regains internet access, even if the app is minimised.

**Attempts at a solution**

Most people are thinking down the 'app posting it' line, which hits the 3 min limit as mentioned.

Is there anything around the server pinging the app (perhaps with a notification) to trigger the app to respond with the required information?

Comment: This will be very difficult, when an app goed in the background it can request to perform a [`Executing Finite-Length Tasks`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) this allows you to run a task for 10 min. (you might be able to request it a second time top run max time 20 min.) Or you need to make sure you app falls in the background running mode, which are: Audio, location, VOIP or accessory. But mis using the background mode for something that it is not ment for will get you app rejected.

Comment: You only get 3 minutes of background execution time now.

Comment: Its not possible to  send network request in background for 5 min.default is run only for 3min .

Comment: Can't edit my comment any more, but yes it is not max 3 minutes, which you might be able to stretch to 6. You could also look in to background fetch, then the OS will give you some time to do background fetching, it is not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: You can use a push notification with `content-available:1`; if the device is offline then the notification will be held for some time and delivered when the device comes back online but it will be discarded without delivery eventually. You may need to send the push every day